# Python Access function vars in decorator

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, decorator

i want to to the following:

Let's say i have a following function:

```
def query(self, url, method = 'GET',payload=None):
    if method == "GET":
        result = requests.get(self.api_base_url+url, auth=self.__auth_token, verify=False)
        print (result)
    elif method == "POST":
        result = requests.post(self.api_base_url+url, auth=self.__auth_token, data=payload, verify=False)
        print(result)
    elif method == "PUT":
        result = requests.put(self.api_base_url+url, auth=self.__auth_token, data=payload, verify=False)
        print(result)
```

i want to measure the time those rest calls need. So i started to build a decorator which will measure the time of rest calls.

```
def timing(f):
        def wrap(*args):
            time1 = time.time()
            ret = f(*args)
            time2 = time.time()
            time_took = time2-time1
            print (time_took)
        return wrap
```

Now i want to print the payload. But only for the PUT and POST requests and not for GET requests. So i need to check the argument `method` in my decorator, but i'm not able to accesse this argument inside my decorator. Especially i want to do something like this:

```
def timing(f):
        def wrap(*args):
            time1 = time.time()
            ret = f(*args)
            time2 = time.time()
            time_took = time2-time1
            if args[0].method == 'PUT' and args[0].method == 'POST'
                print (time_took + args.[0].payload)
            else:
                print (time_took)
        return wrap
```

Question:

How can I access the arguments of the function within my decorator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like you tried, but without `.method`. `args` is a tuple of arguments.

```
def deco(f):
    def inner(*args):
        print(args[0])
        return f(*args)
    return inner


@deco
def foo(a):
    pass

foo('a')
# a
```

If you don't want to keep track of the arguments' indexes you can use `kwargs`.

```
def deco(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs['a'])
        print(kwargs['b'])
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner


@deco
def foo(a, b):
    pass

foo(a=1, b=2)
# 1
# 2
```

Comment: The problem is, that the argument "method" ist not inside the "args" list. Why ? print args[0] prints me the object of my class

Comment: @Constantine Because you are passing it as a keyword argument. See my updated answer.

Comment: kwargs is empty. and i dont understand why